# Pulling back Lie-valued forms to get curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

According to Lemma 1 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Weil_homomorphism#Definition_of_the_homomorphism ,
if $\Omega$ is the curvature of a connection on a principal $G$-bundle $P\xrightarrow{\pi}M$,
then for any $G$-equivariant ((real/?)complex-valued) polynomial $f$ on $\frak{g}$, there exists a unique 2-form on $M$ which pulls back to $f(\Omega)$.

Does anyone have an explicit counter-example showing that $\Omega$ itself need not be the pullback of any ($\frak{g}$-valued) form on $M$?

Edit: following the suggestions of the comments below, I realized the connection itself can't be a pullback since it doesn't vanish along the fiber directions (whereas the curvature does).

Comment: For starters, you need a horizontal form on $P$. So focus on that with your question.

Comment: Sorry, wouldn't a connection already give a horizontal form?

Comment: Absolutely not. A horizontal form evaluated on a vertical vector field must give $0$. Of course, that's only the starting point for your question.

Comment: Hmm, but a connection one-form $A$ should give a horizontal distribution $\mathrm{ker}A$, which should surely admit a global horizontal form through some partition-of-unity argument? (Perhaps not uniquely, though I'm not sure what uniqueness is "up to" in that case.)

Comment: Go learn more. The connection form is $\mathfrak g$-valued and restricts to the fiber to be the Maurer-Cartan form of $G$.

Comment: What I mean is that $A$ may be viewed as a section of the bundle $\mathrm{Hom}(TP,\frak{g})$, and the kernel of $A$ in this sense is a horizontal distribution.

Comment: Indeed, $\mathrm{ker}A$ should be complementary to $\mathrm{ker}\pi_*$; by e.g. condition 2 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Formal_definition , we know $A : TP \rightarrow \frak{g}$ is (fiberwise) full-rank, and also $\mathrm{ker}A$ is linearly independent to $\mathrm{ker}\pi_*$; by dimension-counting now $\mathrm{ker}A$ and $\mathrm{ker}\pi_*$ should be complementary in $TP$?

Comment: So that proves $A$ is very much not horizontal. The curvature form, however, is. But it still cannot be a pullback from the base. Why?

Comment: I didn't imply $A$ is horizontal, I meant that $\mathrm{ker}A$ is a horizontal distribution, in that it is complementary to $\mathrm{ker}\pi_*$ in $TP$. Is this the definition of horizontal distribution?
Also thank you, I did not realize the curvature cannot be a pullback from $M$. I will think more about this.

Comment: I never mentioned the word distribution. I said the firm itself had to be horizontal for $\pi$. I then told you what that means.

Comment: I see, so the problem is that there is a horizontal distribution $E = \mathrm{ker}A$, but this doesn't necessarily admit a horizontal form (i.e. a form whose kernel is complementary to $E$ in $TP$)?

You mentioned the curvature is horizontal; since it's a 2-form, here do you mean $\Omega(v,-)$ is 0 whenever $v$ is in the fiber directions (thus complementary to $E$)?

Comment: You have a huge misconception here. A $1$-form is horizontal if its kernel *contains* the vertical space, i.e., the tangent space to the fiber. Nothing to do with complementarity. Forget about the horizontal distribution. Indeed, this all makes sense when you have an arbitrary submersion $\pi\colon X\to Y$ and you want to know when a form on $X$ is the pullback of a form on $Y$.

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation. 

Also, does the principal bundle curvature vanishes along the fiber directions? (I.e. $i_X \Omega = 0$ whenever $X$ is tangent to the fibers.) Is this what you meant when you said the curvature is a horizontal form?

Comment: Yes, right. But that’s not yet enough to see it’s the pullback of a form from the base.